# How do I extract the external JSON data and put it into a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm using a plugin called 'tidy table' to display my JSON content. Basically, I want to tabulate the content of the JSON file into a html table, that can be sortable.

The code they've supplied only displays JSON content embedded into it (http://jsfiddle.net/2NH4u/). However, I have an external file I want to include (this is MY code http://jsfiddle.net/NNvSV/).

The code that's tripping me up is:

```
$.getJSON('onesies.json', function(res) {

    // generate HTML table
    $('#container')
         .TidyTable({
            columnTitles : res.headers,
            columnValues : res.rows
        });
```

Comment: You need data to mess with: `onesies.json` is obviously not an avaiable url

Comment: @watson, I think it's the OPs local JSON file. OP, does the JSON parse? jQuery tends to fail silently if JSON doesn't parse.